# Non-blocking python threading

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to run several threads at once which can hang up to 30 seconds because they wait on a response from a table call (and is why I am using a thread pool instead of a process pool). I was curious if there is any way to achieve non blocking threads within python? I ran a small test using datetime.datetime.now() and it looks like my script is waiting up to 30 seconds to call my next concurrent.futures.threadpoolexecutor thread. Here is a look at how I'd like to run multiple non blocking threads.

```
database = Database.Database()
results = {}
table_get_pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
results.update(collect_attributes(results, table_get_pool.submit(database.dbcallone).result()))
results.update(collect_attributes(results, table_get_pool.submit(database.dbcalltwo).result()))
```

I know because of the gil threads aren't a strong suit but since most of the time these threads are running at 0% since they wait on a response it made no sense to use a processing pool if I could avoid it. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like your database library isn't releasing the GIL while blocking for query response.

Comment: Do you have the source code for your database library ? Reading it will tell you whether the GIL is released or not.